Geth: Number of finalized block is missing
I recently had an unexpected power outage and when I try to launch my geth + prysm clients, they seem to have lost track of the blocks. I'm about a day behind on the eth.blockNumber. I get the following errors:
Geth: ERROR: Number of finalized block is missing
Prysm: Started to do an 'initial sync'
I tried to do a "geth db inspect" on the /gethDataDir/chaindata folder, but that returns a:
"failed to hex-decode 'prefix': hex string without 0x prefix"
Is there a good method to recover from such a scenario?
Thanks in advance for your replies!
